# Buffer flushing in ostream overloading

Tags: c++

What is the recommended way to use buffer flushing when overloading ostream in C++? Do I just disable buffer flushing in the beginning and enable it in the end? If so should i flush the buffer before returning the ostream? I have never seen this part mentioned in any ostream overloading reference.
EDIT: Lets say i have a class with a lot of members. The ostream operator prints each member. How should i write the ostream overload?

```
struct ToPrint {
char firstMember;
char secondMember;
int number;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ToPrint& instance) {
    os << instance.firstMember << '\n'
        << instance.secondMember << '\n';
    if (instance.number > 0)
        os << instance.number << '\n';
    return os;
}
```

Comment: What?, why can't you just do std::endl or something?

Comment: I'm not asking how to flush the buffer, I'm asking if i should flush it for every line i write to it.

Comment: General rule of thumb is to flush when the buffer is full, on close, or when instructed to. Different media may require different handling though. Could we trouble you for an expansion of the question to better describe your goals and the media to which you are streaming?

Comment: What do you mean by "ostream overloading"?

Comment: OK, so you're talking about overloading `operator<<`? Why do you need to do anything special with buffering?

Comment: Well i was thinking what if I'm writing a class with N members that flushes after outputting each of them and i have a loop that loops over M objects printing each one, that would mean M*N buffer flushes when only M are necessary. Also what if the program terminated for some reason when its in the middle of the output it would output just half of the members wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended use of buffer flushing for output streams in C++ is to not do it. Unless you have special requirements, the default behavior of the stream will work just fine.

Comment: So i should use '\n' instead of std::endl to try and prevent unnecessary flushes.

Comment: When you’re writing to the console it doesn’t make much difference. It’s slow, because the display has to draw all the text. But if you redirect the output to a file, all those flushes kill performance. `’\n’` ends a line. That’s all that’s needed.